# carousel slider cell phone swipe effect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Basically this below link has a carousel slider for the android cellphone. I'm trying to create the same effect with my website.

[image]

I'm trying to create a website like [this](http://www.februe.de/) but with the user being able to swipe the screens to go to the next screen, instead of auto or buttons...

What type of free downloadable carousals are available online that causes this responce from the carousal when the user swipes a website on a cell phone screen. I can only find free ones that don't have the swipe effect.

Comment: Most carousels are for desktop websites, not mobile websites, so there is no reason to listen for touch/swipe events.  You could always use one of those and add in your own listener.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use jGestures

There is a plugin called [**jGestures**](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/). You can consider using them.

> A jQuery plugin that enables you to add gesture events such as 'pinch', 'rotate', 'swipe', 'tap' and 'orientationchange' just like native jQuery events. Includes event substitution: a "tapone" event can be triggered by "clicking", a "swipe" by performing a swipe-ish mousegesture.

The syntax is simple:

```
jQuery('#swipe').bind('swipeone',eventHandler);
```

*And yeah, this is Windows 8 Touch compatible!*